# Mistake in my coding, but not sure how to correct it, wonder if anyone can give a hand?

Tags: php, database, arrays, foreach

Hi I encounter a problem with the foreach function in php... i used the function to input results of an array into the database. Forexample, If the Array (3,5,7), the system should input 3 different entries into the database. However, in my case, it only created 1 entry and totally ignored the other 2. May I know if anyone can spot my mistake?

i have created the a form with checkboxes and trying retrieve the value and give each value a individual array for example:

```
<form name="appoptions" id="applicationoptions" method="post" action="s_apply_now.php">
<table width="100%" class="apptable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" value="1" /> CAT 2PG</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" value="2" /> CAT 1OR</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" value="3" /> CAT 2TT</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" value="4" /> CAT 3PG </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" value="5" /> CAT 2OR</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" value="6" /> CAT 3TT</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" value="7" /> CAT 4PG</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" value="8" /> CAT 3OR</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

After clicking on confirm, it will then proceed to the processor page. In my processor page I tried to extract the value but i realise its in an array:

```
<?php
session_start();
include'Connections/database.php';
$conn = dbConnect ();
    if (! $conn)
    die("Couldn't connect to MySQL");
    $user = $_SESSION['eid'];
    $query = "select MED  from emp where EID = '$user'";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $conn);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$med = $row['MED']; 
$user =$_SESSION['eid'];
$class=$_POST['class'];
$cat_arr=$_POST['cat'];


$i = 0; /* for illustrative purposes only */

foreach ($cat_arr as $cat) 
{
    if ($med=='no')
    {

        if (! $conn)
        die("Couldn't connect to My SQL");

        $query = "insert into permit (EID, PTYPE, STATUS) values ('$user,$cat, 'medical')";
        $result = mysql_query($query,$conn);
        header ('Location:medical_question.php');
        $i++;
    }
    else
    {

        if (! $conn)
        die("Couldn't connect to My SQL");
        $query = "insert into permit (EID, PTYPE) values ('$user,$cat)";
        $result = mysql_query($query,$conn);
        $i++;
    }
 }
dbDisconnect($conn);
 ?>
```

I am not everysure if for each is the mistake but I think its around there...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, I wouldn't put the db connection inside the loop. Second, are you getting any errors, and have you dumped the $cat_arr to see what it contains?

Comment: A few things...first of all, you shouldn't connect to and disconnect from your database in your loop. This is unnecessary overhead. You should connect before your loop and disconnect after. Secondly, we can't see what `$med` is. Try doing this: `var_dump($cat_arr); var_dump($med);` before your loop to see what it contains.

Comment: @Travesty3 Sorry guys...i never indlude the whole code...i added in already...do you mind to breifly explain what is car_dump for?? because the php manual website is not very clear...i do not quite understand it.

Comment: @Hubert: `var_dump` will basically output the contents of a variable. It's great for debugging purposes. If you `var_dump` an array, it will spit out the contents of the array.

Comment: @Travesty3 oh thanks so i add `var_dump($cat_arr);` to below `$cat_arr=$_POST['cat'];` right or there is no specific place i need to put?

Comment: @Hubert: Correct, put it after `cat_arr = $_POST['cat'];`. Again, this is for debugging purposes, so that when the script is called, you (the developer) will see what `$cat_arr` contains. The `var_dump` should be removed once the bug is fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see a few different things wrong with your PHP code:

1. You shouldn't connect/disconnect MySQL in your loop. This is unnecessary overhead. Instead, connect before your loop and disconnect afterwards.
2. You need to sanitize any user input before using it in a query. Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).
3. You should also move your `header('Location:medical_question.php');` line outside of your loop, and you should change it to `die(header('Location:medical_question.php'));` in order to stop the rest of your script from executing (assuming that's what you want to happen).
4. You need to fix the single-quotes in your queries:

   `insert into permit (EID, PTYPE, STATUS) values ('$user,$cat, 'medical')`

   should be:

   `insert into permit (EID, PTYPE, STATUS) values ('$user', '$cat', 'medical')`

   And the same thing for your other query.

In the end, your script will look more similar to this:

```
$conn = dbConnect();
if (!$conn)
    die("Couldn't connect to MySQL");

$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['eid']);
$class = $_POST['class'];
$cat_arr = $_POST['cat'];

foreach ($cat_arr as $cat) 
{
    $cat = mysql_real_escape_string($cat);

    if ($med == 'no')
        $query = "INSERT INTO permit (EID, PTYPE, STATUS) VALUES ('{$user}', '{$cat}', 'medical')";
    else
        $query = "INSERT INTO permit (EID, PTYPE) VALUES ('{$user}', '{$cat}')";

    mysql_query($query);
}

dbDisconnect($conn);

if ($med == 'no')
    $nextPage = "medical_question.php";
else
    $nextPage = "next_page.php";

die(header("Location:{$nextPage}"));
```

---

**SQL Injection example:**

Suppose your query looks like this:

```
$user = $_GET["user"];
$cat = $_GET["cat"];
$query = "insert into permit (EID, PTYPE, STATUS) values ('$user', '$cat', 'medical')";
```

What would your query look like if I passed in a value like this for `user`:

```
`'); DROP TABLE permit; /*`
```

That would turn your query into this:

```
insert into permit (EID, PTYPE, STATUS) values (''); DROP TABLE permit; /*', 'cat', 'medical')
```

This is **definitely** not what you wanted to happen. When you sanitize the input using `mysql_real_escape_string`, it will escape the single-quote character and either the query will fail or the entire string will be inserted instead of being executed.

---

**UPDATE:**

The reason you want to move the `header` outside of the loop will be easier to understand if you know exactly what the function does:

When you call the PHP `header` function, you are telling PHP (on the server-side) to send a HTTP header to the browser (on the client-side). In the case of `header('Location:...')`, you are sending a HTTP header that causes the browser to redirect to a different page and disconnect from the current PHP script.

So this is the course of events that happens:

1. The PHP script sends the HTTP header, and depending on the latency, it can take some time for the browser to receive it.
2. The browser interprets the header and redirects to the location you specified, which also sends a disconnect message to the currently executing PHP script.
3. Again, depending on latency, it can take some time for the server to receive the disconnect message from the browser.

Between the time that the PHP script sends the header and then receives the disconnect message, the script is still executing. There is no way to tell how much code the script will execute before receiving the disconnect message, so you cannot rely on this at all. This is why you should `die` upon sending the header.

Knowing that this is how the PHP `header` function works, the only reason you would possibly want to put this inside the loop, is if you want the current script to stop execution in the middle of the loop depending on some certain condition. Like this:

```
foreach ($vars as $var)
{
    if ($var == "stop")
        die(header("Location:anotherPage.php"));

    // do something as long as $var != "stop"
}
```

This will loop through the `$var` array until it comes to the value `"stop"`, at which time it will send a redirect header to the client and stop execution.

The difference with your example is that (before you edited it) your loop contained a single `if-else` statement, and in both the `if` ***and*** in the `else`, you had the header-redirect call. So no matter what, it would be sent on the first iteration of the loop, which doesn't make sense. If this is truly what you wanted, you wouldn't be using a loop. It would only be executed once, which defeats the purpose of a loop.

Sorry for the long-winded response, but hopefully you now have a better understanding of what's really going on in your code.

Comment: sorry i am a little confuse about the sanitise part...u were saying put var_dump() right ?? this is to sanitise the input?

Comment: No, `var_dump` is for you to visually look and see the contents of an array. To sanitize your user input, you use `mysql_real_escape_string`. Read the definition of SQL injection for a better understanding on why sanitation of user input is necessary.

Comment: understood! Thanks...i went to read up more on mysql_real_escape_string() in php manual...

Comment: oh can i ask one more thing?? why must we have {} around the variables?? sorry if its a noob qns...

Comment: Good. I went ahead and posted an example of a SQL injection attempt, so you recognize the risk. The brackets (`{}`) are not required, I just find them helpful to recognize the boundaries of your variable names inside strings. It can help in cases like this: `$variable = "Hello"; $string = "{$variable}_world!";`. If you didn't have the brackets there, the `_world!` part would be connected to the variable name, so this helps to separate the variable name from the rest of the string.

Comment: ooh...ok by inserting {} it wouldn't cause any difference to the query right?? if thats so i think its good way to organise codes...Thanks so much i will implement them and try

Comment: Right..you're not changing anything, just making it clearer where the boundaries of your variable name are. I also find that it helps me spot variables within strings in my text editor (Notepad++).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9615/discussion-between-hubert-and-travesty3)

Comment: hi...can i ask why for your code, the header is outside the loop?

Comment: See updated answer. It's a bit long, but hopefully it helps you get a better understanding of what's going on with your code.

Answer (score 2):

It's only inserting once because after doing the first insert, you are redirecting to medical_question.php.

Move this redirect to outside of the foreach:

```
header ('Location:medical_question.php');
```

Also, you might as well move the db connect to before the foreach too.

Comment: Well, technically, since he doesn't `die()` or `exit()`, the script will continue executing. But I agree that it should be moved out of the loop.

Comment: @Travesty3: Wouldnt the header redirect as soon as it finished the first foreach?

Comment: It can continue but as soon as the browser receives the `Location` it will disconnect and the script will stop executing at that point. In this case it looks like that happens before MySQL receives the next insert query, especially given that a new db connection is created on each iteration.

Comment: Guys...sorry my mistake...my intention is that `if ($med=='no')` then go to `header ('Location:medical_question.php');` else go tothe enxt page which i haven create yet but it will be the page to tell user that permit successful applied for.

Comment: @MrCode If i want to set the page to go to `header ('Location:medical_question.php');` `if ($med=='no')` or  go to the next page which i haven create yet but it will be the page to tell user that permit successful applied for. where should i put the header?

Comment: @Hubert: Whenever you want the page to stop executing is where you should put the header. If you want the entire script to execute before redirecting, then it should go at the bottom of your script. If you want it to stop at a certain point, that's where you should put it. But you should make sure to `die()` or `exit()`, [otherwise the script may continue executing](http://www.devchunks.com/php/php-header-redirect-dont-forget-to-die/). It isn't the PHP function `header` that causes the page to redirect, it's the browser that performs this action, so there could be a delay depending on latency.

Answer (score 1):

1. strings are marked by '$string' (apostrophe) into a sql query

   $query = "insert into permit (EID, PTYPE) values ('$user','$cat')";
2. you can initialize just one db object ($db) with proper connection, and use it where you want: see http://php.net/manuel/en/ref.mysql.php

Eg:

```
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'db');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        exit('Connect failed: '. mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `val`) VALUES (1, 'peace'), (2, 'love')";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo 'Done';
    }
    else {
        echo 'Error: '. $conn->error;
   }
   $conn->close();
```

This is just a raw example.